# How to see my wlan ip? Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, wireless

I know i need to go to terminal and enter

> `ifconfig`

but when i do that i only get etho and lo informaion. So anyone know something?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: You don't seem to have an active wireless network connection then. Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 2):

The ifconfig command should show you the status of all your active devices.

An alternate command is: `ip addr` or `ip address`

This cli should show you yhour wlan ip if it's activated:

```
$ ip address | egrep wlan
```

Are you sure you have a wlan active connection?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way you can see your wlan ip address is to click on the wifi icon and go to Connection information... Then Bingo!

Comment: I am using also using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS